# How to make ctrl-p plugin for vim only search within a given list of directories

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I am working in a mammoth codebase. There are too many files and folders at the top-level. But, I work in a small corner of the codebase - no more than 10 directories hanging off of the top-level. How do I give ctrl-p the list of these 10 directories and have it search only inside them? Right now, even with `let g:ctrlp_max_files=0`, ctrl-p is having trouble finding my files because I just have too many files.

Comment: You should check this with your plugin support (if that's a plugin)

Comment: `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore` or `g:ctrlp_user_command`. The first is easier to use, the second more powerful.